# How to add SELECT statements in addBatch()?

Tags: java, jdbc

Hi I am trying to execute couple of queries in a batch by using `statement.addBatch(sql)` Now I have found that if query is `SELECT BLAH BLAH` then it throws Exception saying `BatchUpdateExecption` So how do I add SELECT statement inside batch. For e.g. the following does not work because on batch contains SELECT statement

```
st.addBatch("UPDATE")
st.addBatch("CREATE")
st.addBatch("SELECT")
st.executeBatch()
```

One work around is I execute SELECT statement in `st.execute("SELECT")` instead of `st.addBatch("SELECT")`. Are there any recommended ways or best practice for this usecase? Please guide thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Batch statements are basically for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements, they're not intended for a `SELECT` statement nor a DDL statement. If you want to execute a `SELECT` statement, do it in another `Statement` or `PreparedStatement` that won't execute the batch statements.

Answer (score 2):

Even the javadoc says :  typically addBatch is a SQL `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement. It is not designed to be  used for `SELECT` statements.[Refer addBatch(String sql)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch%28java.lang.String%29)

Moreover `addBatch(java.lang.String)` method cannot be called on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement but `addBatch()` supports PreparedStatement.

Comment: *This method cannot be called on a PreparedStatement* yes it can: [`PreparedStatement#addBatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch--).

Comment: Actually java 7 does not support it but as you said java 8 does thanx mate for letting me know.I'm updating it

Comment: Here it says: *Since Java 1.2*.

Comment: well there is difference between addBatch(java.lang.String) and addBatch(), and the answer is in context of what the OP asked not of what else can be done

Comment: Well, the answer didn't specify the method. Now it does.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute them in one connection, one of the options is to add logic like this:

```
if (query.startsWith("SELECT")) {
    // process SELECT query 
} else {
    // process UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE queries
}
```

but in this case, all of your SELECT queries will be executed at first queue